# Issue with CodeIgniter redirect

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

Here i'm creating a login system. Once the user is verified the controller redirects the page to `home`.php.

There are 2 pages here login_registration.php and home.php

login_registration.php consists login and registration form from here the user is redirected to home.php. both the files are in path `C:\wamp\www\CI-Project_1\application\views\login`

The issue is it show `404 Page Not Found` when redirected.

```
 class Login extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
                $this->load->helper('url');
        //LOAD MODELS HERE
        $this->load->model('Login_model');
    }

    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('login/login_registration.php');
    }

    function login_user(){
        $login_btn = $this->input->post('login_btn');

        if($login_btn == TRUE){
            $arr['login'] = array(
                'username'=>$this->input->post('username'),
                'password'=>$this->input->post('password')
            );

            $query = $this->Login_model->users_login($arr);

            if($query->num_rows() > 0 && $query->num_rows() == 1){
                $this->load->library('session');
                $this->session->set_userdata($arr['login']);
                redirect('login/home.php', 'location');
            }
            else
            {
                $this->index();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $this->index();
        }
    }
}
```

### THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: You have not got the home function on controller Login

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [codeigniter views documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html)

> The .php file extension does not need to be specified unless you use something other than .php.

So, the correct code is as follow:

```
$this->load->view('login/login_registration');
```

Also you are not using the redirect function correctly, as i don't see any **home** function inside **login** controller. If you somehow have **home** function inside **login** controller then why are you using **.php** after function name?

Check the [codeigniter redirect documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#redirect) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You have to mention the name of your controller and method name where you want to redirect something like this

```
redirect('controllername/methodname');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
            $this->load->helper('url');
    //LOAD MODELS HERE
    $this->load->model('Login_model');
}

public function index(){
    $this->load->view('login/login_registration.php');
}

public function home(){
    $this->load->view('login/home.php');
}

function login_user(){
    $login_btn = $this->input->post('login_btn');

    if($login_btn == TRUE){
        $arr['login'] = array(
            'username'=>$this->input->post('username'),
            'password'=>$this->input->post('password')
        );

        $query = $this->Login_model->users_login($arr);

        if($query->num_rows() > 0 && $query->num_rows() == 1){
            $this->load->library('session');
            $this->session->set_userdata($arr['login']);
            redirect('login/home', 'location');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->index();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $this->index();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For redirect and `$this->load->view`, don't use `.php`.

Use something like this: 
    `redirect('login/home', 'location');`

Answer (score 0):

Why you going to redirect if you want to call any method from a controller then you can redirect like that:

```
public function home(){
    $this->load->view('login/home.php');
}

redirect('login/home', 'location');
```

But I think you don't need to redirect you can simply load view file just like you already load your registration view. So you just load view Instead of redirect..

```
$this->load->view('login/home.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

To redirect on any function in CI can use `redirect('controller n_name/function_name','refresh');`